# EF4 - Load related entities of detached object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an ASP MVC 3 application using Entity Framework 4 to access data from a SQL Server database.

I have a scenario where I am loading an entity from the database using EF4. I am then able to load the related entities as per normal. After the first load, I cache the entity. This requires it to be serialized. On the next request, I load the same entity, but this time from cache. This causes the object to be detached from the context since it did not originate from there. I am then unable to load the related entities as per normal.

It seems obvious that the reason for this is that the object is detached from the context and thus is not being tracked. I know that when an object is being tracked by the context, it keeps track of the changes and apply them if and when needed by executing the actual SQL statement. But what I'm not sure of is whether the attached state has anything to do with the ability to load related entities.

Ok here are some specifics. This is the model structure. Note that this is simplified and does not include everything necessary to enable EF4 to work with it. This simply demonstrated the structure.

```
public class Segment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SegmentGroup Group { get; set; }
}
public class SegmentGroup 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Segment> Segments { get; set; }
}
```

I am then able to get a segment from the DB or Cache. This is done in a Manager class that. Once again very much simplified.

```
public SegmentManager
{
    public Segment GetSegment(Guid id)
    {
        string cacheKey = ... //generate specific cache key using Guid id
        Segment segment = CacheProvider.Get<Segment>(cacheKey);
        if(segment == null) //does not exist in cache yet - load from db and insert into cache
        {
            segment = repo.Find<Segment>(id); //roughly translates to:
                                              //segment = dbcontext.Segments.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
            CacheProvider.Add(cacheKey, segment);
        }
        else //segment was found in cache - attach to context
        {
            repo.Attach<Segment>(segment); //dbcontext.Segments.Attach(segment);
        }
        return segment;
    }  
}
```

So this then effectively enables me to use this segment manager like this:

```
public ActionResult SegmentGroupName(Guid segmentId)
{
    Segment segment = SegmentManager.GetSegment(segmentId); //Loaded from DB of Cache
    return segment.Group.Name; //Group is accesable when segment is loaded from DB, but not from cache
}
```

So the problem is that I can access the SegmentGroup on the Segment when the Segment is loaded from the DB, but not when it's loaded from cache.

So my question is, what can I do to the segment after it's loaded from cache to enable me to access the related entities. 
I need a generic solution that I can apply to all my model managers in this same pattern because everything is heavily abstracted. 
I'm trying to avoid having to eager load all related entities or manualy loading them after the fact since this will actually be more expensive than not caching at all. I just want things to go back to the way they where before caching. :)

Please note that the code demonstrations is very much simplified, and you will need to make some realistic assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that I ran into that I refer to as Schrodinger's Code... I came across a similar issue where I was passing my model to my view, but when trying to access the related entities, I received errors referring to the object context being closed. I was able to get around this without reopening the object context by having observed the related entities prior to passing the main entity to my view.

For instance, if I was dealing with your Segments and Groups, it would be something of the following

```
Segment segment = repo.Find<Segment>(segmentId);
var segmentGroup = segment.Group;
```

I'm not going to do anything with segmentGroup after this, but simply because I observed it, it now exists. Without that prior observation, the system was unsure about how to handle this because that extra call hadn't been made to the database, but since it had been observed in this instance, the Group object's data has been associated with the Segment object.

Weird, I know... it exists, but it doesn't exist... we know it is there, but we have to see it to prove it... Hence why I refer to this scenario as Schrodinger's Code...